# BigO time complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

What is the bigO time of this algorithm?
Input: Arrays A and B each sorting n>=1 integers
Output: The number of elements in B equals to the sum of prefix sums in A

```
c=0
for i=0 to n-1 {
  s=0
  for j=0 to n-1 {
    s=s+A[0]
    for k=1 to j {
      s=s+A[k]
    }
  }
  if B[i]=s {
    c=c+1
  }
}
return c
```

I got n(n+2)(n+2)+1 which is n^3+4n^2+4n+1 which is O(n^3)

Comment: I see 2 loops.  one based on 1/2 the other = O(n^2 / 2) = O(n^2).  Bubble sort-esque.

Comment: Heh. Two comments saying the answer was right and then OP changes the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the BigO here, all you have to do is to find out the number of loops how many of them are nested.
In your case you have two loops (nested) hence it would be O(n * n) = O(n^2)

P.S Even though your inner loop does not go as many times as the outer one the BigO still remains the same.

Comment: This was based on the old version of the question. According to your revised one, you need to add one more 'n' for your extra loop which makes it O(n*n*n)

Comment: Well, it's _slightly_ more involved than that. You have to count how many times each inner loop executes for each time through the outer loop(s).

Comment: That is true but in the end factors and constants are ignored while representing the BigO. My answer was based on that. :) But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @noMAD: I disagree with your generalization. Concider the following inner loops: `for (i = 0 to n) for (j=0 to n/i)`. The inner loop will repeat `n*Hn` times where `Hn` is the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) which will yield `O(nlogn)`. Your claim is true only if the inner loop's limit is linear to the outer one's iteration number, and both loop counters are increasing by a constant.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the order of growth, formally, you may proceed like the following:

[image]